# How do I get hardware info such as CPU name, total RAM, etc. with VB6?

Tags: winapi, vb6

Title pretty much explains it all. I need to get some hardware information such as CPU info, and total RAM with VB6. Ideally, it would return something like this for the CPU:

> Intel Core 2 Quad Q8500 2.66 GHz

and for the RAM something simple like an integer for the amount of MB the computer has total.

Comment: About memory info with API see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412014/2369384)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use WMI to get this information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=VS.85).aspx

This information is also available in the registry (if WMI isn't to your liking):
HKLM/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/System/CentralProcessor

NOTE: Registry keys and locations may change. The WMI API is designed as a more stable source for this kind of information.

Answer (score 6):

in plain C, if interested:

```
#include <intrin.h>

int cpuInfo[4] = {-1};
char CPUBrandString[0x40];

memset(CPUBrandString, 0, sizeof(CPUBrandString));

__cpuid(cpuInfo, 0x80000002);
memcpy(CPUBrandString, cpuInfo, sizeof(cpuInfo));

__cpuid(cpuInfo, 0x80000003);
memcpy(CPUBrandString + 16, cpuInfo, sizeof(cpuInfo));

__cpuid(cpuInfo, 0x80000004);
memcpy(CPUBrandString + 32, cpuInfo, sizeof(cpuInfo));
```

Comment: The CPU brand string is not guaranteed to end with a null terminator, so `CPUBrandString` should be 0x41 characters long, not 0x40, if it is going to be used in any context where null terminated strings are expected.

Comment: Would be nice to show an example output

Comment: To answer myself: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz

Answer (score 4):

RAM - [GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc300158%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ([GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on earlier versions)

CPU - [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (not in the desired friendly form, I'm afraid).  There is a very extensive discussion of more detailed CPU info retrieval [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/hardwareinformation/article.php/c9087__2/Three-Ways-to-Retrieve-Processor-Information.htm).