# Is there any ways to use msinfo32.exe in my program?

Tags: c++, msinfo32

I'm writing a program to maintain computers at my workplace. I want to use msinfo32 to automatically collect system information about computers in network remotely and use this data in my program.

The only way I found is to manually connect using interface of msinfo32, export all data and then parse it with my program. But I want to improve this process and do it automatically, update all info automatically etc.

**Is there any way I could collect all pc info remotely using msinfo32 from inside of my program?**

Please, send me link to how-to with code examples, or explain why I can not do this or how I could.

*Sorry for my english, thank you for your attention.*

UPD: possibly, I can run msinfo32.exe from inside, but I rather use library than running external program in cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You should use WINAPI functions, because msinfo32 does not provide console output interface, which could be best solution.

Related: [How do I get hardware info such as CPU name, total RAM, etc. with VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443864/how-do-i-get-hardware-info-such-as-cpu-name-total-ram-etc-with-vb6)

You can also use registry keys to check any system *settings*, all documentation is in the net. Getting system *information* using registry is not reliable, though.

[Msinfo32 documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490937.aspx)

Comment: If a `.nfo` file can be generated programmatically, the data can be parsed from it and then the file can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly do you need to gather. You have some WinApi functions and classes that can give you the system info.
[GetSystemInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724423(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Computer System Hardware Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx) 
But I think it's not that bad to use msinfo32.exe directly if it works.

Comment: I thought a little bit and came to a solution. Possibly, it will make my program more cross-platform. What if I will not include this part of work inside of my program, but just include parser of some json doc, for example. And on the other hand I will provide platform-specific utilities or scripts to get hardware info and make correct json-file. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Yes it's possible of course. But you need to think about how large your network or computer's group is, what OS do you use and basically is it worth it? :D

Comment: Yep, I think it is worth it. Number of computers is up to ~300 approximately. And all of them are distributed on the territory with large area (~1km^2). Huh, so I prefer to collect all info remotely and automatically rather than running around like a crazy :)

Comment: I see :D 
Yea so I think the scripts would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if in 2015 there was already the "/nfo" option that allows you to have all the results exported to a file.
So just execute:

msinfo32 /nfo "c:\delme\msinfo32.nfo"

and then, via XML, read the desired results.