# remote system CPU and RAM usage in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

Can you please suggest how to retrieve remote system CPU and RAM usage in VB 6.0 I need retrieve the remote system cpu utilization and ram performance using vb6.0.Please help as on that.

Thanks in advance ......

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get current CPU and RAM usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404731/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-vb-6)

Comment: The remote system would obviously need to be running some sort of server software that makes that info available. If you could just retrieve that from a random remote system that'd be a big issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a Client/Server application using DCOM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266717/en-us?fr=1). The Server Application could [get information from Windows API](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213267).

Comment: Another approach is to [use WMI to access remote system information](http://www.ehow.com/how_7711632_access-remote-system-information-vb6.html) without the server application.